# how to create multisign wallet from scratch?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I am new in creating smart contract 
I want to create a multisign wallet from scratch??

I want to create accounts 1st and want to hold private key safely

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you want to do? There's a pretty great multisig wallet from the Gnosis team https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet. You can use it to learn, or deploy one.